# Hyperlinked and creating a HTML Page that is nested in a table

Tags: php, hyperlink

So I have a html table that is automatically generated after passing a query to my database. I want to create a hyperlink within my html table to a page that will pull more detailed information from a Second Table.

I was thinking of using the Tablecell creator that pulls from the First Table, and modifying so that it would encompass the table's contents with hyperlink tags. I was thinking it would look like this.

```
foreach(new TableRow(new AutoArrayMaker($stmt->fetchAll()) as $rowend => $row){
    echo <a href = "the reusable HTML Page">;
    echo $row;
    echo </a>;
}
```

Is my idea sound from a coding standpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, echo's need to be in quotation marks " So that code wouldn't fire.
There are a few ways you can output HTML. The first is using echo's:

```
echo "<a href=\"https://google.com\">Google</a>";
```

Notice how I put a back-slash before hand? This is what is known as an escape. This puts the character after into a letter depending on what it escapes to. See php docs: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php (as my description of it was poor)

The other option would be to run out of php then join back on so to speak:

```
<?PHP
foreach(new TableRow(new AutoArrayMaker($stmt->fetchAll()) as $rowend => $row){
  ?>
    <a href="abc">
    <?PHP echo $row; ?>
    </a>
  <?PHP
}
```

However, this is not advised.

Edit:
Also, you can make your own table very simply:

```
<table>
<?PHP
  foreach($stmt as $row){
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="abc"><?PHP echo $row[id]; ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?PHP
}
?>
</table>
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp for more info.